# Client-side blazor can't load two isolated js files

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I'm trying to load two isolated js interop file. One works and the other doesn't (even tho the content is identical). I can load a js from an external lib (MyBlazorlib) but I can't seem to get the CSB app lib interop to work.

```
var module = await jsr.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
  //"import", "/_content/MyBlazorLib/lib_interop.js"); // OK
    "import", "/_content/CSBAppLib/app_interop.js");   // "Failed to fetch.." Exception!
```

I get this exception:

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:5001/_content/CSBAppLib/app_interop.js
```

Is there a way to look into the dlls and figure out where the js files are named or located?

**Edit**: I'm using CSBAppLib which is both a Client-side app and Blazor lib.  Perhaps CSB apps can't have their own isolated js?

Answer (score 3):

I think you forget to add `(./)` before `/_content/`:

```
var module = await js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
"import", "./_content/CSBAppLib/app_interop.js");
```

You need also to add the preceding JavaScript module to a .NET library as a static web asset `(wwwroot/app_interop.js)`.
I hope that can help you a little, please also check [microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-javascript-isolation-and-object-references)

Comment: The `./` didn't help. But maybe I can just load it as a static asset `/app_interop.js`.  Thanks!

Comment: The `./` did help in my case, inside a RCL with host cshtml in a Blazor app project.